# PHP сценарий ничего не записывает в data при использовании axios

Tags: php, vue.js, axios

Передаю данные из vue в скрипт на PHP, который отправляет письмо. Проблема в том, что response.data возвращает пустую строку. Ранее не использовал для этих целей axios. Прошу помощи или хотя бы подсказки.

Сервер: OpenServer + Apache

P.S Отправка данных срабатывает при событии submit на форме (там ошибку точно можно не искать); Письмо не отправляется; Значения, передаваемые  в axios, берутся из vuex; Ответы от сервера записываются в реактивные данные для вывода в представление, на время разработки, ибо собирается как веб-компонент.

App.vue

```
import store from "./store";
import axios from "axios";
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";

export default {
  store,
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      serverResponse: "",
      serverReject: "",
      postURL: "/scenarios/send_data.php"
    };
  },
  methods: {
    sendDataToScenario() {
      axios
        .post(this.postURL, {
          fullname: this.getUserFullname,
          userData: this.stringifyUserData
        })
        .then(response => (this.serverResponse = response))
        .catch(reject => (this.serverReject = reject))
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["getUserFullname", "getUserData"]),
    stringifyUserData() {
      let printing = "";
      for (let value in this.getUserData) {
        printing += value + ": " + this.getUserData[value] + "; ";
      }
      return printing;
    }
  }
```

send_data.php

```
<?php

function send_mail() {
  $post = (!empty($_POST)) ? true : false;

  if ($post) {
    if ( isset($_POST['fullname']) ) { $user_fullname = json_decode($_POST['fullname']); }
    if ( isset($_POST['userData']) ) { $user_data =  json_decode($_POST['userData']); }

    $error = '';

    if (!$error) {
            $from = "lrobot@host.com";

            $to = "admin@host.ru";

            $subject = "Новый заказ требы";

      $message = "<br>Заказчик: $user_fullname <br>Данные: $user_data";

            $headers = "From: $from \r\n".
            "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n" . 
      "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8" . "\r\n";

      $mail = mail( $to, $subject, mb_convert_encoding($message, 'utf-8', mb_detect_encoding($message)), mb_convert_encoding($headers, 'utf-8', mb_detect_encoding($headers)) );

      if ($mail) {
        echo "success";
      }
    } else {
      echo $error;
    }

  } else {
    echo "Нет данных";
  }

  die();
}

?>
```

Comment: в php файле объявлена функция, но она сама себя не запускает. Поэтому ничего не происходит

Comment: @ArchDemon Как я этого не заметил... Спасибо, теперь функция запускается, дальше думаю разберусь